# Change value of string array at debug eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an application, but to test something, I need to change value of a `String[]`.

But when I do it using **change value** in **variables** tab, everytime it gives error.

I have tried using :

`{"string1", "string2"}`

`["string1", "string2"]`

`[string1, string2]`

etc. But had no luck. Can anybody plese tell how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, you can't actually add(change) value in array while debugging.

But there is a work around, you need to assign new string array to this reference like,

`new String[]{"string1", "string2"};`

But this will remove old entries, so if you want to only add new values best way is to, copy old values from the **variables** tab.

`new String[]{old values..., "string1", "string2"};`

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect.  Just don't forget the semi-colon to terminate the end, as Eclipse is expecting a valid Java Statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use below command in the change value window.

```
return new String[]{"new string"};
```

Comment: Add more description of your answer. It'll make answer a bit comprehensive.